# Can I disable constraints in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: iphone, button, label, constraints, xcode4.6

If starting a new project in Xcode 4.6 and when adding a button in a ViewController it is always followed by constraints. I have found that this project does not run on the iPhone 5 simulator (iOS5). On iPhone 6 simulator it runs ok. It is the constraints causing the crash. Removing the button and it runs ok on both 5 and 6 simulator.
If I use an older Xcode (before the constraints) to start the project and continue with Xcode 4.6 the constraint are gone.
But is there a way to disable the constraints from start in Xcode 4.6 to make a project run also with iOS5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to go file inspector tab where will find the autolayout , then uncheck this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. So easy. I did not find that button because I did not look in the file inspector. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah that's called [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) and was introduced in iOS 6.0 (and like any feature that's unsupported in a previous version of iOS, it crashes).

To disable Auto Layout on your nib file, see this [blog](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/) article.